# Silverlight business application initialize check

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am using the Business Silverlight application. I have incorporated some MVVM into this and were off an running with it. We are using some telerik controls, mostly the ribbon control and the docking. We register all the telerik ribbon controls in the about.xaml.cs file, the method is DisplayUI - its here where we register the docking control then we register the ribbon after this. What happens is that when you click the ABOUT link it shows our first tab with buttons(perfect). when you click the HOME link next to the ABOUT link, we go back to the home page..but when you click the ABOUT link again it registers the controls again so we end up with two tabs that are the same.

Is there a way to check to see if this about.xaml.cs file has already been initialized? Im guessing that is has a handle on the first call in memory as I am able to see the first tabs rendering..

Thanks

here is the about code

```
    public About()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DisplayUI();

        this.Title = ApplicationStrings.AboutPageTitle;
    }
```

that display UI does all the work in registering the dockpanel and the ribbons. We'd like to not  have the DisplayUI() called if this has already been rendered once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it by event handler can you unsubscribe from the event at the end of the method? Without seeing some code it's hard to work out what to change.

It's not the nicest way of doing it, but if this code needs to run once and only once then you could have a static boolean variable on the class set to false and when you call DisplayUI you check the value of this. If it's false you set it to true and run the method, and if it's true you just return.

Comment: @Matthew..thanks for reading and sending some feedback. i have updated my question. if you need more details let me know..thanks!

Comment: I think we'll need the DisplayUI() method as well.

Comment: Updated my answer. It's not the most elegant way of doing it but I've a feeling I'd need to see pretty much the whole project / framework to give a better answer!

Comment: Thanks! yes not the most elegant way..I tried this about 4 hours ago, but did not make the bool static. just had it as private bool _isLoaded; i still have to run DisplayUI but i put this check around the RegisterRibbonButtons...thanks!